# "of both which" or "of which both"

Tags: word-choice, sentence, semantics

Consider the following sentence:

> This takes a lot of time and money to keep going, [. . .] I have little.

Which would fit best in that ellipsis?

- of both which
- of which both
- both of which

In my mind (and to my ears), *of both which* sounds correct, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Both of which," but you need another "of":

> This takes a lot of time and money to keep going, both of which I have little 
>   of.

Comment: Cheers. It's surprising how nuanced English can be even to a native speaker (with an English lit degree, no less). `of both which` and `of which both` sounded great to me, and is something I have been using for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

[Kevin](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/131540) is right that *both of which I have little of* is good; so is:

> This takes a lot of time and money to keep going, of both of which I have little.

Moreover, one of your original suggestions —

> This takes a lot of time and money to keep going, of which both I have little.

— also seems correct to me, but only in formal writing (or speech by a lawyer). In general, *both of which* is the same as *which both*; likewise, *both of whom* is *who/whom both*, *both of them* is *they/them both*, *all of them* is *they/them all*, and so on. Some of these are more common than others, and context helps determine commonness also, which is why I recommend against *which both* in your sentence in informal settings but wouldn't usually recommend against *they all*.